# How can I write code to hide table from select the option button

Tags: excel, vba

I use option button to set for hide or unhide table. How can I do for make that with vba code or Other methods ? Thank You (PS. Sorry for my language)

[image]

Comment: Where is the code you are using and what problems are you having with it?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while doing it manually?

Comment: Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Sheet1.Range("C8:G11").Show
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    Sheet1.Range("C8:G11").Hidden
End Sub

Comment: Yes, I want to recording a macro to do that.